# Generate migration script that prints status along the way with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

With `dotnet ef migrations script` I can generate an SQL script that migrates my database to the latest version; with `--idempotent` I don't even have to care what version it's currently at, since it will check the history table before applying a migration.

However, I can't figure out if there's a way to make it print status along the way. I'd like it to, for example, `PRINT` that it either applied or skipped a migration (so I know if something was done or not).

Is it possible to generate a script with that feature using `dotnet ef migrations script`?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the migrations with Sql() statmenets like

```
Sql("PRINT 'Success'");
```